# Appending divs at the end of the html document on ie8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I wrote a aminated menu with background images with jQuery which works as expected on all browsers including ie8, hier is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $("#mainMenu ul li").css('background-image', 'url(images/nav/menuItem.png)');
    $("#mainMenu ul li:first-child").css('background-image', 'url(images/nav/menuFirst.png)');
    $("#mainMenu ul li:last-child").css('background-image', 'url(images/nav/menuLast.png)');

    $('#mainMenu ul li:first-child').append('<div class="first"></div>');
    $('#mainMenu ul li:last-child').append('<div class="last"></div>');
    //All Items other than the first and the last
    $('#mainMenu ul li:not(:first-child, :last-child)').append('<div class="item"></div>');


    $('nav#mainMenu ul li').hover(

        function() {

            $(this).children('div').stop(true,true).fadeIn('500');
            $(this).children( "a" ).stop(true,true).animate({color: hoverColour},200);  
        }, 


        function() {

            $(this).children('div').stop(true,true).fadeOut('500'); 
            $(this).children( "a" ).stop(true,true).animate({color: "white"},200);      

    });

});
```

THE PROBLEM is that ie8 appends divs at the end of the html file, take a look at the screenshot!

[image]

Comment: Can you demonstrate this behaviour with a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might refer to the last- and first-child selector. Look at this [chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/). Have you tried jQuery's `.first()` and `.last()` operator?

Comment: I removed the first-child & last-child operator and thsi is still hapenning. I tried :   $("#mainMenu ul li").css('background-image', 'url(images/nav/menuItem.png)');
 
 $('#mainMenu ul li:not(:first-child, :last-child)').append('<div class="item"></div>');
 
 $('nav#mainMenu ul li').hover(
  
  function() {
   
   $(this).children('div').stop(true,true).fadeIn('500');
    
  }, 
 
  
  function() {
  
   $(this).children('div').stop(true,true).fadeOut('500'); 
   
  
 });

Comment: Try this: $("#mainMenu ul li").first().css('background-image', 'url(images/nav/menuItem.png)');

Comment: No, that didn`t work! BUT removing the conditional statement:  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="javascript/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]--> solves the problem!
which means html5shiv.js is the problem! i used html5shiv.js as a solution because the internet explorer doesn`t support HTML5 tags prior to ie9